# I am having issues making my code responsive for smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

[image: large screen layout]
[image: This is what it looks like on a smaller screensize (576px)]

I am trying to make my code responsive so the layout on a smaller screen matches that of the larger screen where the times are side by side with the days.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```html
<section class="maps-link">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center" > <!--justify-content-center-->
          <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="operating-hours">
            <h5 class="text-uppercase py-5"> Working hours</h5>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Monday</p>
                <p>Tuesday</p>
                <p>Wednesday</p>
                <p>Thursday</p>
                <p>Friday</p>
                <p>Saturday</p>
                <p>Sunday</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
                <P>9:00 - 18:00</P>
              </div>
              <div class="operation-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn float-center my-3">Book Now</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2907.301070286598!2d-79.90350282363299!3d43.22414697112562!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x882c9ade812413cd%3A0xbfa94fb004dc6200!2s345%20Limeridge%20Rd%20W%2C%20Hamilton%2C%20ON%20L9C%207C9%2C%20Canada!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1684233996645!5m2!1sen!2suk" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: If you want the layout to be the *same* on small displays why did you use the `-md-` classes which only apply to *medium and larger* displays?

Comment: You HTML is nonsense anyway. Read it out. "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,  Sunday, 9:00 - 18:00, 9:00 - 18:00, 9:00 - 18:00, 9:00 - 18:00, 9:00 - 18:00, 9:00 - 18:00, 9:00 - 18:00". It makes no sense! Don't try to use CSS to rearrange text that doesn't make sense when you read it unstyled. Use a description list or a table.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML structure is a bit wrong, you want to logically match the text and structure as best as possible so you avoid these issues from the get-go and avoid having to fix them with the CSS.
Since you want these to be rows it would be best to change it to something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Monday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Thursday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Friday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Saturday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Sunday</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">9:00 - 18:00</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap has nice documentation that you can check out with proper examples for columns (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/), and how to use the col and sizes with the breakpoints correctly.

At the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/ they have this size reference table which always helps when building responsive layouts:

```
Breakpoint         Class infix  Dimensions
X-Small            None         <576px
Small              sm           ≥576px
Medium             md           ≥768px
Large              lg           ≥992px
Extra large        xl           ≥1200px
Extra extra large  xxl          ≥1400px
```

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>Monday</p>
          <p>Tuesday</p>
          <p>Wednesday</p>
          <p>Thursday</p>
          <p>Friday</p>
          <p>Saturday</p>
          <p>Sunday</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
          <p>9:00 - 18:00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="operation-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn float-center my-3">Book Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2907.301070286598!2d-79.90350282363299!3d43.22414697112562!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x882c9ade812413cd%3A0xbfa94fb004dc6200!2s345%20Limeridge%20Rd%20W%2C%20Hamilton%2C%20ON%20L9C%207C9%2C%20Canada!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1684233996645!5m2!1sen!2suk" width="100%" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```